# Export Data to a hive table on querying another table

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I have table1 with multiple duplicate ID's. My aim is to move formatted data (on removing duplicate records) from Table1 to Table2. Schema of Table1 & Table2 is same.

Here, either method works, to update Table1 with formatted data or to move Data to Table2.

Can someone please help me!

Comment: is the table in `HIVE`? if so you can just use `insert overwrite table table1 select distinct f1,f2,...,fn from table1`

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE yourTable ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (columnwithduplicates)
```

EDIT

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD CONSTRAINT idx_name UNIQUE (columnwithduplicates)
```

this removes duplicate rows

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT column1,column2,etc
FROM table1
```

provided the structure is the same

Comment: First command to remove duplicates is not working. It is giving error "Failed to parse near ignore...."

Comment: I don't know if the syntax in hive is different for creating a unique index.